# Redirect to custom Wordpress login page - but still have a Forgot Password link

Tags: wordpress

I used the code found at [Redirecting Wordpress's Login/Register page to a custom login/registration page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976781/redirecting-wordpresss-login-register-page-to-a-custom-login-registration-page) - to do as the post title says...

However, now when a user lands on my custom login page but have forgotten their password I can't include a 'recover your password' link...

I can see that it's because "wp-login.php?action=lostpassword" begins with "wp-login.php" so the Forgot Password link is just being redirected to the custom login page... but don't know what to do about it...

Can anyone suggest a way to do it please? Or an alternative method?

Answer (score 0):

hi use this instead rather then what you have got in previous answer .

1-drop this in your function file of your teme

```
add_filter('site_url',  'wplogin_filter', 10, 3);
function wplogin_filter( $url, $path, $orig_scheme )
{
$old  = array( "/(wp-login\.php)/");
$new  = array( "account/"); //this can be change to login or whatever or may remain there
return preg_replace( $old, $new, $url, 1);
```

2- Redirect with .htaccess :add a new rule just after RewriteBase / in your .htaccess pust this ----> RewriteRule ^account$ wp-login.php

NB :please notice that account term is in your function snippet and also in your .htaccess  and will apear in your permalink instead of wp-login.php.
so your url will appear like so with the codes above for register/lgin/lostpassword actions :

www.yoursite.com/account/?action= register

www.yoursite.com/account/?action= login

www.yoursite.com/account/?action= lostpassword

hope it helps and sorry for my english i am better at french ;)