# how to change the default login page of wordpress from wp-login.php to custom login page?

Tags: php, jquery, redirect, wordpress

how to change the default login page of wordpress from wp-login.php to custom login page. So that any request for login by any user should redirect to custom login page instead of wp-login.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's an answer from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976781/redirecting-wordpresss-login-register-page-to-a-custom-login-registration-page), put in functions.php:

```
add_action('init','possibly_redirect');

function possibly_redirect(){
 global $pagenow;
 if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
  wp_redirect('http://google.com/');
  exit();
 }
}
```

Into "http://google.com/" enter the URL of the custom page.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have one thing to ask you.  I have renamed wp-login.php with name wp-login.php plugin. So shall I use that renamed name in that code or wp-login?