# How do you redirect the wordpress login and register page to a custom login and register page?

Tags: php, wordpress

Solved: Please check @Brasofilo solution on [Redirecting Wordpress's Login/Register page to a custom login/registration page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976781/redirecting-wordpresss-login-register-page-to-a-custom-login-registration-page)

I am using the [WPforms](https://wpforms.com/) plugin to create my own login and register forms in combination with the [login-logout](https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-logout/) plugin. The login-logout plugin links to the default wordpress login and register pages, but I would like to use the custom WPforms pages that I created.

So far, I tried to follow [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976781/redirecting-wordpresss-login-register-page-to-a-custom-login-registration-page).

The first solution:

```
add_action('init','possibly_redirect');

function possibly_redirect(){
 global $pagenow;
 if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
  wp_redirect('http://google.com/');
  exit();
 }
}
```

This allows me to redirect to my custom login page, but also redirects the 'register' button to my custom login page.

The second solution in that thread:

```
function possibly_redirect(){
  global $pagenow;
  if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['wp-submit'] ) ||   // in case of LOGIN
      ( isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='logout') ||   // in case of LOGOUT
      ( isset($_GET['checkemail']) && $_GET['checkemail']=='confirm') ||   // in case of LOST PASSWORD
      ( isset($_GET['checkemail']) && $_GET['checkemail']=='registered') ) return;    // in case of REGISTER
    else wp_redirect( home_url() ); // or wp_redirect(home_url('/login'));
    exit();
  }
}
add_action('init','possibly_redirect');
```

This solution gives me a message that link doesn't exist.

Please let me know if any other information would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I added an answer over there that solves your problem. `init` is the wrong hook.

Comment: @brasofilo It worked, Thanks for your help!