# Redirect Logged Out Users in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

When a user clicks on something like "recommend this article" and the user is not logged in, it redirects them to the wp-login.php page. However, I don't want non-admin to be redirected to the backend login. Instead, I want them to be redirected to the homepage where they can login via a woocommerce login page.

I installed [the Dashboard Access plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-dashboard-access-for-non-admins/), but it didn't work. When I click "recommend this article" as a front-end user, I still get redirected to the backend login page.

Comment: Do you want to redirect users into Homepage after the login?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirecting Wordpress's Login/Register page to a custom login/registration page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976781/redirecting-wordpresss-login-register-page-to-a-custom-login-registration-page)

Comment: @developerme No, I mean redirecting non-logged in users to homepage (when they click something that requires login).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Plugin "ZM Ajax Login & Register "  for custom 'Login' & 'Registration'  page,

well there is a notification from Wordpress, but it still works
OR you can change default login/registration page with Plugin "Custom Login URL "  with your woo commerce pages 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-login-url/

I hope this is helpful for you

Comment: well I'm trying to redirect non-logged in users so not sure if this is the solution