# How can I change the default Wordpress Login Page link for a button?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using the OceanWP theme with the WP Job Manager plugin to build my job listing website.

When a user tries to 'Post a Job' when they are not logged in the WP Job Manager plugin shows a default login button which directs them to the default wp-login.php page: http://prntscr.com/pr86qn

But I wanted the user to be diverted to a new custom login/registration page I created as it does not have the 'Wordpress' logo on it and also allows users to register if they do not have an account.

When I clicked the "inspect element" option on this "sign in" button, I can see the link here: http://prntscr.com/pr8951

So I would like to change the link:

`<a class="button" href="https://www.XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.XXXXXXXXXX.co.uk%2Fpost-a-job%2F">Sign in</a>`

(I have XX'd out my website name as I would prefer it not to show in any google search results)

...so that it will direct the user to my new custom login/registration page instead.

Could anyone advise which file I could change this link from or if there is a better way of changing this link?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try **LoginPress Plugin** to customize default login Page 
 [https://wordpress.org/plugins/loginpress/](http://LoginPress%20Plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a more advanced function originally mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976781/redirecting-wordpresss-login-register-page-to-a-custom-login-registration-page)

Add this to your function file.

```
function possibly_redirect(){
  global $pagenow;
  if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['wp-submit'] ) ||   // in case of LOGIN
      ( isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=='logout') ||   // in case of LOGOUT
      ( isset($_GET['checkemail']) && $_GET['checkemail']=='confirm') ||   // in case of LOST PASSWORD
      ( isset($_GET['checkemail']) && $_GET['checkemail']=='registered') ) return;    // in case of REGISTER
    else wp_redirect( home_url() ); // or wp_redirect(home_url('/login'));
    exit();
  }
}
add_action('init','possibly_redirect');
```

Please go through FTP